# How to map host UID to container UID using Podman?

Tags: podman

I am trying to start and NGINX as unprivilaged user to just serve files from a directory.
I need to map container UID (`nginx`) 101 to my current host UID 1000 so it can access mount data

What I try:

```
podman run --rm -i -p 9876:8080 \
--uidmap 101:@1000:1 \
--volume `pwd`:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
docker.io/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
```

however it fails

```
Error: initializing ID mappings: UID setting is malformed expected ["uint32:uint32:uint32"]: ["101:@1000:1"]
```

where [Podman docs](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html) says it should work with `@1000` but yet it throws an error. It is hightly possible that I don't understand what docs says, but at least it should not throw such errors.

Is it possible to easily map rootless host UID to contnainer UID?

Quote:

> Referencing a host ID from the parent namespace

> As a rootless user, the given host ID in --uidmap or --gidmap is
> mapped from the intermediate namespace generated by Podman. Sometimes
> it is desirable to refer directly at the host namespace. It is
> possible to manually do so, by running podman unshare cat
> /proc/self/gid_map, finding the desired host id at the second column
> of the output, and getting the corresponding intermediate id from the
> first column.
>
> Podman can perform all that by preceding the host id in the mapping
> with the @ symbol. For instance, by specifying **--gidmap
> 100000:@2000:1,** podman will look up the intermediate id corresponding
> to host id 2000 and it will map the found intermediate id to the
> container id 100000. The given host id must have been subordinated
> (otherwise it would not be mapped into the intermediate space in the
> first place).
>
> If the length is greater than one, for instance with --gidmap
> 100000:@2000:2, Podman will map host ids 2000 and 2001 to 100000 and
> 100001, respectively, regardless of how the intermediate mapping is
> defined.

```
Using podman 4.6.2
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.6.2
API Version:  4.6.2
Go Version:   go1.18.1
Built:        Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [git commit](https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/18713/commits/91b8bc7f13f9757dc57738a05923dc3c9c6d3190) shows that the functionality was added to Podman 4.7.

The git commit message also mentions the new syntax to prepend a `+` to **--uidmap**

> To simplify this, **the second usability improvement** is to be able to use:
>
> --gidmap "+20000:@2000:1"
>
> where the plus flag (`+`) states that the given mapping should > extend any previous/default mapping,
> overriding any previous conflicting assignment.

I did a quick test with rootless Podman. This command does not fail on Podman 4.9.0:

```
$ podman run \
   --rm \
   -i \
   -p 9876:8080 \
   --uidmap +101:@$(id -u):1 \
   --volume $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
   docker.io/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
```

Note that

```
   --uidmap +101:@$(id -u):1
```

is equivalent to

```
   --uidmap +101:0:1
```

because the intermediate UID 0 is always mapped to the regular user on the host, the host UID `$(id -u)`

An alternative: Mapping the regular user on the host to a specific container user can also be done with

```
--userns=keep-id:uid=$uid,gid=$gid
```